# length of string generated using .split() method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm extracting **the first word** after a **space** is encountered from a string using `.split()` method:

```js
var word = ("Looney Tunes").split(" ", 1);
alert("Word: " + word + ", its length = " + word.length);
```

Why does the above code gives the length of the string as **1** instead of **6**?

Comment: `word` is an array not string. `split()` creates an array

Comment: array with 1 item as per your requirement of `split(,1)`

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef thanks. That was too simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

split returns an Array. To access the first element you need access the array contents: i.e. word[0] should be "Looney"